# "На столе лежала (не)раскрытая книга, а рабочая тетрадь". Как нужно писать с не"?

Tags: частица-не, частица, противопоставление

На столе лежала (не)раскрытая книга, а рабочая тетрадь.

Противопоставлены существительные, а не определения: лежала не книга, а тетрадь.

Но что-то мешает написать слитно в этом случае.

Comment: Так противопоставление и мешает написать слитно.

Comment: На столе лежала не раскрытая книга, а тетрадь - *тетрадь* противопоставлена *раскрытая книга*. Может быть еще: на столе лежала раскрытая не книга, а тетрадь, - тогда *тетрадь* противопоставлена *книга*.

Comment: А мне МЕШАЕТ само предложение, оно выглядит надуманным и искусственным. Вряд ли такую конструкцию  можно встретить в литературе. Да и сама ситуация сомнительная.  Что здесь вообще происходит? Почему ожидали увидеть раскрытую книгу, а видим тетрадь? Если только детектив какой (с расследованием) или фантастика))  Для решения задачи нужен КОНТЕКСТ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если очень хочется слитно, а текст – "родной" (как говорят о ключе в детективах, исключая отмычку), то запросто:

*На столе лежала нераскрытая книга, а рабочая тетрадь – почему-то под столом.*

На столе лежал**и** нераскрытая книга **и** рабочая тетрадь.

Ежели же текст не "родной", а вполне себе чьего-то сочинения, то раздельно (не буду воровать всеразжёвывающие комменты к вопросу). Сочинитель ожидал увидеть раскрытую книгу, но не сбылось, не судьба: он обнаружил лишь рабочую тетрадь. И сообщает он это урби эт орби посредством отрицания.

> Противопоставлены существительные, а не определения: лежала не книга,
> а тетрадь.

Ну да.

---

О! Исчо сочинилось (только это уже будет искусственный язык, но формально – почему бы и нет):

*На столе лежала не нераскрытая книга, а рабочая тетрадь.*

Comment: Из ответа: *На столе лежала нераскрытая книга, а рабочая тетрадь – **почему** под столом.* Мне кажется, что надо использовать или *почему-то*, или *отчего-то*, имеющие значение "по какой-то причине".

Comment: Спасибо, Римуля! Не почему, а почему-то. Ща как исправлю!